# Javascript to continue or cancel the submit button

Tags: java, javascript

My jsp has this code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Transfer ULD" onclick="doSomething();" name="_eventId_transferULDTransition"/>
```

`doSomething()` is a javascript method

```
function doSomething() {    
    var transferType = document.getElementById('equipmentType').value;
    if(${uldSelector.baseLoadToUse.uldEquipType} == 02 && 
        (transferType == 01 || transferType == 13 || transferType == 07)){
        var r = confirm("Still want to tranfer Air Container?");
        if (r == true) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have 4 to 5 conditions in the method..

When user clicks on 'OK' it should continue and on 'CANCEL' it should not...

But, It submits on both cases..using spring webflow, spring MVC and Java.

Any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The onclick function needs a return. Like

```
<input type="submit" value="Transfer ULD" onclick="return doSomething();" name="_eventId_transferULDTransition"/>
```

Now you return false within your function. But actualy the onclick method does not return a value.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a return on the click action

```
onclick="doSomething();
```

needs to be

```
onclick="return doSomething();
```

BUT it would be better to be doing this on the form level with onsubmit.

```
<form onsubmit="return doSomething(); >
```

Why on the form? Because it is possible to submit the form without clicking the button. Enter key in a textbox will submit it.